# apacitex bibliography stile does not show citations properly

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I'm trying to use apacite to manage my references style.
I'm satisfied with the style of the bibliography, but not the citations. They appear as a number between square brackets, which is not, by any means, close to the APA citation style. How am I supposed to get the citations to appear as actual APA-style ones?
There is also something weird which may be relevant, and it's that the only commands I can use for citations are \cite and \citep (which both result in the output describred earlier) - if I try to use \citeA, the references are taken as error because of, supposedly, not being defined.

This is how I'm setting it up:

```
\usepackage[index]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacitex}
```

I am using pdfLatex as compiler on ShareLaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @mvkorpel Just checked it locally on an MWE written from scratch and it works flawlessly. Definitively it has something to do with ShareLaTeX rather than with TeX itself. I have uploaded the project to Mega (https://mega.co.nz/#!UMdAhDbS) and will post the key below. In the meantime, I'm going to try to fix the errors that arise when I try to compile the project locally since, althought this would not answer the question, it would indeed fulfill my necessities anyway.

Comment: AgSUUPrFFDhVz8ULGQxoZkohnf8j-jiWCzIumhLTe2g

Comment: I took a look at the list of packages loaded in your document. This looks like an issue in the way you are using `apacite` and `natbib`. Please read the relevant part of the [`apacite` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf): "Using natbib for citations".

Comment: Yes, I just figured out about that too. I'll post a self-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong options for natbib. Upon removal of the "square" and "number" options, citations now appear in the proper format (I'm using "sort" and "round").

Comment: You could try using the `natbibapa` option of `apacite` instead of explicitly loading `natbib`. According to the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf), this "better satisfies the APA rules and fixes some compatibility problems".

Comment: I haven't realized any major differences but, since the source citing the option is reliable, I agree that it is better and have adopted it. Thanks again.